# IIS 7 HTTPS not working

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-7

I am relatively new to managing Microsoft IIS servers, and am having trouble getting port 443 (HTTPS) to work externally on my server.

I have installed a SSL from Godaddy and have used the "SSL Diagnostic v 1.0" program to verify that it's installed correctly and has a proper public key on the server to make the signing valid.

I have followed each and every step on the instructions that GoDaddy have provided at the following URL and verified they were completed correctly.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/iis-7-install-a-certificate-4801

I have also ensured that I have added the port 443 (HTTPS) binding to my website in IIS Manager, and am able to access the site via HTTPS via localhost on the server. However, I am unable to access the same site via HTTPS remotely, on my laptop for example.

I have checked my firewall to ensure it is allowing connections through port 443, and I believe it is (screenshot attached)

[image]

At this time I'm pretty stumped at what the issue could be. I am running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 7. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be or any tips on how to diagnose the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED....the issue was Windows Azure. You see I am using a Windows Azure Virtual Machine, and you have to create an HTTPS endpoint for Azure to traffic any requests on port 443 to your site.

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Amazon Lightsail.
I missed the Firewall Permission for https:

[image]